# No application encryption key has been specified. livewire

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-livewire

I'm running an application with livewire, when I give the command "`php artisan serve`" it runs normally without any error, but when I connect the xampp server with laravel, after a few seconds the livewire accuses this error "`No application encryption key has been specified.`"

Comments:

I have already run the following commands:

`php artisan key:generate`

`php artisan config:cache`

`php artisan optimize:clear`

already put in .env in production mode, no positive result.

Comment: maybe you have a env variable that is overriding it (have you checked the .env?)

Comment: Yes, there is no variable in conflict with the APP_KEY, this error only happens when I turn on the server in XAMPP

Comment: Sounds like you are changing a different file than what is being used.